# CursorIndexOutOfBounds error when changing views

Tags: android

```
07-05 23:23:27.497: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.fttech.books/com.fttech.books.creatBook}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

07-05 23:23:27.497: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(390): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

I keep getting these errors when i run i change views and it calls my onResume method to re-populate EditText fields. Here is my code for on resume:

```
protected void onResume(){
    Log.v(tag, "In onResume!");
    Cursor it = mDbHelper.fetchBook(mRowId);
    super.onResume();
    mDbHelper.open();
    setRowIdFromIntent();
    if (it.moveToFirst()) {
       populateFields();


    }
```

Here is my setRowIdFromIntent method:

```
private void setRowIdFromIntent(){
    if(mRowId == null){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null 
        ? extras.getLong(DbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                :null;
    }
```

PopulateFields method which retrieves information from the database if the activity is paused and then resumed, such as when i change from porttrait to landscape.

```
private void populateFields() {
    if(mRowId != null){
        Cursor books = mDbHelper.fetchBook(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(books);

        bookTitle.setText(books.getString(books.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_BOOK)));
        bookAuthor.setText(books.getString(books.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_AUTHOR)));
        bookIsbn.setText(books.getString(books.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_ISBN)));
        ratingBar.setRating(books.getFloat(books.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_RATING)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `moveToFirst()` method of the cursor. Your code should be something like:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    \\ populate fields
} else {
    \\ not found!
}
```

Also make sure that your query returns the columns you are trying to fetch.

Comment: The only thing im trying to do is just incase the user has text typed into the edittext box and then they change the view to portrait i dont want them to lose the information they already typed. Would this be the best way of doing this?

Comment: I update the populate field to what you said it should be now i get a nullPointerException error cause by the Cursor it = line.

Comment: You got it wrong, you should do that in the populateFields method, using the "books" cursor.

Comment: Also if you are interested in saving the state of the activity, refer to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Comment: Awesome! it worked, But from my code i think it may be better to store my info in a bundle and restore it vs doing the populate in onResume? it seems less expensive. What do you think?

Comment: That seems less expensive than the way im doing.. it may be better. How would i do it for onPause? @OVerride onpause(Bundle savedInstanceState) doesnt work.

Answer (score -1):

I have written a ORM framework for that. https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman

You can easily write Android applications using SQLite with that. It uses your Java classes  (you can create `Book` class in this case) as database tables (entities).

If you use this framework, you won't see cursors at all. All you'll see is going to be:

```
List<Book> books = Model.fetchAll(Book.class);
```

then you'll have a list of all books in the database. You won't see column mappings, database and table generation at all. Very useful in your case.